# Kotlin Documentation: Link to methods with different signatures?

Tags: android-studio, javadoc, kdoc

In Java, we have something like this:

```
/**
 * Link1: {@linkplain java.io.Writer#write(int)}
 * Link2: {@linkplain java.io.Writer#write(char[],int,int)}
 */
```

Clicking on the links take to different methods.

I could somewhat achieve the first link with this:

```
[Link1 label][java.io.Writer#write(int)]
```

I also tried with another example (to check if its not a fluke)

```
[Another Link label][java.io.Writer#write(java.lang.String,int,int)]
```

I have been trying these on Android Studio. The Koltin links are not directly clickable, but the documentation if seen in "Rendered view" (with Ctrl+Alt+Q), the links show up.

I am having a hard time with the second Java example. This does not work:

```
[Link1 label][java.io.Writer#write(char[],int,int)]
```

If anyone has resolved this, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do so, according to [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-doc.html#inline-markup).

> Note that KDoc does not have any syntax for resolving overloaded members in links. Since the Kotlin documentation generation tool puts the documentation for all overloads of a function on the same page, identifying a specific overloaded function is not required for the link to work.

Comment: Extremely underwhelming to be honest.